# many to many in gorm v2 error on foreign key

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm finding it difficult to define many to many relationship using Gorm in following cases

```golang
features(feature_id, name, slug)
operations(operation_id, name, slug)
feature_operations(feature_id, operation_id)

type Feature struct {
    FeatureID  int64       `gorm:"primaryKey;column:feature_id" json:"feature_id"`
    Name       string      `validate:"required" json:"name"`
    Slug       string      `json:"slug"`
    Status     string      `json:"status"`
    Operations []Operation `gorm:"many2many:feature_operations;foreignKey:feature_id"`
    appModels.BaseModel
}
```

When using `feature_id`, I get error

> column feature_operations.feature_feature_id does not exist

When using `id`, I get error

> invalid foreign key: id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you are not using the convention that gorm suggests where you name your primary key columns just `id`

so in your case your `foreignKey` should be the name of the field and you also need to use `References` to specify column that you want to reference. See the example here:
https://gorm.io/docs/many_to_many.html#Override-Foreign-Key

What you need is this:

```
type Feature struct {
    FeatureID  int64 `gorm:"primaryKey;column:feature_id"`
    Name       string
    Slug       string
    Operations []Operation `gorm:"many2many:feature_operations;foreignKey:FeatureID;References:OperationID"`
}

type Operation struct {
    OperationID int64 `gorm:"primaryKey;column:operation_id"`
    Name        string
    Slug        string
}
```

After this the join table will be `FEATURE_OPERATIONS` with two columns `FEATURE_FEATURE_ID` AND `OPERATION_OPERATION_ID`

If you dont like the redundant column names then you need to use the two additional attributes `joinForeignKey` and `joinReferences` to choose your own names for the columns like so:

`gorm:"many2many:feature_operations;foreignKey:FeatureID;joinForeignKey:FeatureID;References:OperationID;joinReferences:OperationID"`

All this extra work is needed because your primary keys are `FEATURE_ID` and `OPERATION_ID` instead of just `ID`
If you can rename the column to follow the convention, you will notice life is much easier with gorm

Comment: Thanks for reply. @Kaus2b I've tried adding references as well but resulted with same error I mentioned above. https://go.dev/play/p/bSbUiNqCfYS?v=goprev

Comment: @SujitBaniya update answer above with more specific details

Comment: Thank you for the response. Seems I've to change column names and follow gorm. But unfortunately, I can't change the current table structure `feature_operations(feature_id, operation_id)`. So I've to use all those implementation.